# On canvas, a way to make it so multiple apples fall in game?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a game (using HTML5 canvas) that involves catching falling apples, i know, how original! I am having trouble finding a way to make it so multiple apples fall?

Here is the link to the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pgkL09j7/14/

```
var apple_x = 100;
var apple_y = 0;
var basket_x = 100;
var basket_y = 100;
var points = 0;

var basket_img = new Image();
basket_img.src = "http://s18.postimg.org/h0oe1vj91/basket.png";

var Countable = function() {}

     //Background colour of canvas
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

     //Here is the event listener
c.addEventListener("mousemove", seenmotion, false);



                        //////////////////////

      function seenmotion(e) {

            //This is the code for the mouse 
            //moving over the canvas.
       var bounding_box = c.getBoundingClientRect();
       basket_x = (e.clientX - bounding_box.left) * (c.width / bounding_box.width) - basket_img.width / 2;
       basket_y = (e.clientY - bounding_box.top) * (c.height / bounding_box.height) - basket_img.height / 2;
                        }

                        function start_game() {
                            setInterval(game_loop, 50);
                        }


                        function game_loop() {
                            // The code above is called every 50ms and is a 
                            // frame-redraw-game-animation loop.

                            c.width = c.width;

                            // Below is the code that draws the objects
                            draw_apple(apple_x, apple_y);
                            draw_basket(basket_x, basket_y);

                            // Below is the code that updates the balloons location
                            apple_y++;
                            if (apple_x > c.width) {
                                apple_x = 0;
                            }

                            //Here is the collision detection code
                            if (collision(apple_x, apple_y, basket_x, basket_y)) {
                                points -= 0.5;
                            }


                            //Here is the code for the point system
                            points += 1;

                            // and let's stick it in the top right. 
                            var integerpoints = Math.floor(points); // make it into an integer
                            ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif";
                            ctx.fillText(integerpoints, c.width - 50, 50);
                        }



                        context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

                        function collision(basket_x, basket_y, apple_x, apple_y) {
                            if (apple_y + 85 < basket_y) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (apple_y > basket_y + 91) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (apple_x + 80 < basket_x) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            if (apple_x > basket_x + 80) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }

                        // Code to stop the game when we're finished playing
                        function stop_game() {

                        }

                        //Code for the ball
                        function draw_apple(x, y) {
                            var apple_img = new Image();
                            apple_img.src = "http://s15.postimg.org/3nwjmzsiv/apple.png";
                            ctx.drawImage(apple_img, x, y);

                        }

                        //Code for the basket
                        function draw_basket(x, y) {
                            ctx.drawImage(basket_img, x, y);

                        }
```

Comment: Have you considered an array of apples instead just one apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this on your previous question, so I'll repeat it here.  You will need to maintain an array of apples, but you will also want to check out `requestAnimationFrame` in order to improve performance.  Things are going to get janky for you, and you probably already noticed it when you move the bucket around.  I've modified your fiddle to demonstrate exactly how you might modify your program to support multiple apples falling at different rates of speed.  (Set `apples_per_level` to 2 or more to immediately see multiple apples -- or just play the game, and watch as they accumulate!).

https://jsfiddle.net/h82gv4xn/

Improvements include:

- Fixed scoreboard
- Added level progression (Level increases every 10 apples)
- Allowance for many many more apples on screen (play to level 9).
- Apples will fall at different speeds and speed up as the levels increase.
- Uses the animation frame system for *much* smoother animations.
- Relaxed collision handling (The center of the bucket must touch the apple)

It all gets really silly as the levels wind upwards, but it should be a nice example to improve upon.  The relevant javascript follows (this would go into your onLoad function):

```
var game = create_game();
game.init();

function create_game() {
    debugger;
    var level = 1;
    var apples_per_level = 1;
    var min_speed_per_level = 1;
    var max_speed_per_level = 2;
    var last_apple_time = 0;
    var next_apple_time = 0;
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var delay = 1000;
    var item_width = 50;
    var item_height = 50;
    var total_apples = 0;
    var apple_img = new Image();
    var apple_w = 50;
    var apple_h = 50;
    var basket_img = new Image();
    var c, ctx;

    var apples = [];
    var basket = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        score: 0
    };

    function init() {
        apple_img.src = "http://s15.postimg.org/3nwjmzsiv/apple.png";
        basket_img.src = "http://s18.postimg.org/h0oe1vj91/basket.png";

        level = 1;
        total_apples = 0;
        apples = [];

        c = document.getElementById("c");
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        c.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            //moving over the canvas.
            var bounding_box = c.getBoundingClientRect();
            basket.x = (e.clientX - bounding_box.left) * (c.width / bounding_box.width) - basket_img.width / 2;
            basket.y = (e.clientY - bounding_box.top) * (c.height / bounding_box.height) - basket_img.height / 2;
        }, false);

        setupApples();
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

    function setupApples() {
        var max_apples = level * apples_per_level;
        while (apples.length < max_apples) {
            initApple(apples.length);
        }
    }

    function initApple(index) {
        var max_speed = max_speed_per_level * level;
        var min_speed = min_speed_per_level * level;
        apples[index] = {
            x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - 2 * apple_w)) + apple_w,
            y: -apple_h,
            v: Math.round(Math.random() * (max_speed - min_speed)) + min_speed,
            delay: Date.now() + Math.random() * delay
        }
        total_apples++;
    }

    function collision(apple) {
        if (apple.y + apple_img.height < basket.y + 50) {
            return false;
        }
        if (apple.y > basket.y + 50) {
            return false;
        }
        if (apple.x + apple_img.width < basket.x + 50) {
            return false;
        }
        if (apple.x > basket.x + 50) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    function maybeIncreaseDifficulty() {
        level = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(basket.score / 10));
        setupApples();
    }

    function tick() {
        var i;
        var apple;
        var dateNow = Date.now();
        c.width = c.width;
        for (i = 0; i < apples.length; i++) {
            apple = apples[i];
            if (dateNow > apple.delay) {
                apple.y += apple.v;
                if (collision(apple)) {
                    initApple(i);
                    basket.score++;
                } else if (apple.y > height) {
                    initApple(i);
                } else {
                    ctx.drawImage(apple_img, apple.x, apple.y);
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.font = "bold 24px sans-serif";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#2FFF2F";
        ctx.fillText(basket.score, c.width - 50, 50);
        ctx.fillText("Level: " + level, 20, 50);

        ctx.drawImage(basket_img, basket.x, basket.y);
        maybeIncreaseDifficulty();
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }

    return {
        init: init
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael Hays! that was very very kind of you, i can save that to help me now and for future reference!!

Comment: My pleasure -- it was fun!

Answer (score 1):

Your next logical step would be to create an apple `Object` with appropriate properties. Following that, you can store them in an `Array` and animate multiple apples.

Comment: How would I go about creating an apple object?

Comment: @Gerard. This is more a comment than an answer--perhaps move it to the question's comment section? ;-)

Comment: @Sean I suggest you start yourself by searching (with your favorite Internet search engine) for suitable ways of creating objects. Not because I don't want to help, but being able self-help is much more useful - consider this a dual learning opportunity.

Comment: Haha fair enough, it was worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

As Gerard said, you should create an `Array` of apple `Objects`. You can take a look at [this example with balls](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/html5-canvas-bouncing-balls.html) instead of apples.

One you are done with that, I would recommend that you draw all the apples that fall at the same speed in different offscreen canvases and that you animate those instead of going apple by apple if you are planning to add many of them. If they are all going to fall at the same speed, use just one offscreen canvas and move all at once.

Also take a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/ if you have trouble keeping your FPS at an appropriate rate.